# node.js Nest Testing Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test

Tags: node.js, testing

I'm experiencing a timeout error (status code 5000) when attempting to send a request with a body or payload while testing using nest.js . This issue occurs when I use the following code:

await app.inject({
method: 'POST',
url: '/purchase/main-subscription/authenticated',
body // or payload
});

Strangely, when I use Postman, the request works without any issues.

Does anyone have an idea why this timeout error is occurring only when I include a body or payload in my request